elasticsearch unassigned nodes, how to reassign?
My cluster has started to produce unassigned shards
elastic version 7.17.6
What is the process to attempt to reassign these shards to the cluster?
{
  "cluster_name" : "test-prod-cluster",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 25,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 21,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1185,
  "active_shards" : 2370,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 4,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 99.83150800336983
}

I have these 2 indexes with unassigned shards.
I have attempted to reroute these to another warm node but it wasn't working as intended, I may be going around the wrong way to achieve getting these nodes back to the cluster.
"shrink-rtyq-test-2024.06.11-015830" : {
  "status" : "red",
  "number_of_shards" : 1,
  "number_of_replicas" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,
  "shards" : {
    "0" : {
      "status" : "red",
      "primary_active" : false,
      "active_shards" : 0,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 2
    }
  }
}

"shrink-igdz-test-2024.06.10-015824" : {
  "status" : "red",
  "number_of_shards" : 1,
  "number_of_replicas" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,
  "shards" : {
    "0" : {
      "status" : "red",
      "primary_active" : false,
      "active_shards" : 0,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 2
    }
  }
}


Have you experienced some catastrophic node or disk loss in this cluster? Could you post allocation explanation for these shards?

I think the initial error you showed in your first edit had some interesting hints: initial allocation of the shrunken index is only allowed on nodes [_id:"59P4_905R9KR8uCG-rQB_w"] that hold a copy of every shard in the index

The issue that @Val quoted is solvable - you just need to add more storage capacity to the cluster so the node with shrunken index has some room to allocate required shards. The second issue "No data for shard [0] of index [shrink-hhw3-test-2024.06.08-015772] found on any node" means that data for this index is gone and unless you can bring a node where this shard used to be allocated back into cluster, it's gone forever. You need to restore it from backup or reindex.
